# Problems in read column in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, automation

I need to read particular column and only 3 rows by using pandas.
I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
     A      B       C      D
0   ravi   priya    sonue   John
1   priya  sonue   ravi     john
2   john  ravi     priya    sonue
3   sonue john    priya    ravi
```

And I need to access, for instance, the row from 0 to 2 only in only column B.

I tried using df.iloc[0, 2] but it returns the whole b column.

Any help would be appreciated.

so result should be like this

```
B 
priya
sone
ravi
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot use `df.loc[0:2, 'B']` and need positional indexing (e.g. you have not a range index).

If you only want to read the data, you can use chained slicing:

```
df['B'].iloc[0:3]
```

If you need a safe way to index (for instance to assign data, avoiding `SettingWithCopyWarning`), you can use mixed indexing:

```
df.iloc[0:3, df.columns.get_loc('B')]
```

output:

```
0    priya
1    sonue
2     ravi
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: ..thank you , if possible can we get two column using above code like this.  df.iloc[0:3, df.columns.get_loc('B','D')]